# How to fix this ownership error: cannot move out of index

Tags: rust

I am trying to move ownership of structure from "children" to "genomes" in the thread of "create_next_generation", Because part of genomes should be the same value of children, and then the children would be never used. This is the code of the process that indicates the context.

```
fn create_next_generation<'a>(genomes: &'a mut Vec<Genome>, 
      children: Vec<Genome>, gene_mutate: f32, individual_mutate: f32, survive_number: usize){

    for i in survive_number..children.len(){

        
            genomes[i] = children[i-survive_number];       //<--------error
        
    }
}


fn main() {


    let mut genome_list: Vec<Genome> = Vec::new();
                         .
                         .
                         .

    let mut children: Vec<Genome> = Vec::new();
                         .
                         .
                         .
    
    create_next_generation(&mut genome_list, children, values.genome_mutation, 
    values.individual_mutation, values.select_genome)

}
```

and the structure is

```
struct Genome{
    dna : Vec<i32>,
    eval : f64,
}
```

The error is

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of index of `Vec<Genome>`
   --> src/main.rs:109:26
    |
109 |             genomes[i] = children[i-survive_number];
    |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because value has type `Genome`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the intention of your code. Will `children.len() > i` be ever false? If you're trying to shorten the vector, try working with `Vec::swap_remove`. Otherwise, maybe you want to use `children[i-survive_number].clone()`.

Comment: I am sorry, as you indicated, `children.len()` > will be useless. I modified my code, thank you. Then, I tried to use `.clone()` but I got the error of `method not found in Genome`. this means structure which is data type of the Vec does not have clone() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving is not allowed in this case -- you can only move an owned value, but the value you're trying to move here is owned by the `children` vector.  You could make this work with [`std::mem::take()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.take.html) (if `Genome` implements [`Default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/trait.Default.html)), but there's an even easier way to handle this: [`Vec::splice()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.splice).

The splice operation returns an iterator over a range of elements to be removed from the vector, producing them by moving instead of copying.  It doesn't matter too much that the vector is modified since it will be destroyed anyway, but this gives you a simple way to move a bunch of elements out of the vector in a single mutating operation.

Chaining this with `.enumerate()` gives us the index of each element (starting with 0).

```
for (i, v) in children.splice(survive_number..).enumerate() {
    genomes[i] = v;
}
```

It's unclear if you want to replace `genomes` entirely with these removed elements, but if that's the case then this operation becomes a one-liner:

```
*genomes = children.splice(survive_number..).collect();
```

Since you are destroying the vector anyway, you could even use `children.into_iter().skip(survive_number)` in place of `children.splice(survive_number..)` in the above examples, which will consume the vector.